# Choosing an Analytic Function to Fit to Data

Tags: distributions, dataset, goodness-of-fit, fitting, curve-fitting

I have a dataset that I am trying to fit an analytic function to in order to use the functional shape as a PDF. Disclaimer, I am a physicist so I don't have too thorough background in statistics, and so I am basically wondering how do I decide what type of function to use just by inspection?  This is the shape I am trying to model. It clearly will have an exponential component, I'm just not sure how to model the low x section.

If someone could guide me towards the correct type of function to use and explain the thought process behind the choice that would be much appreciated.

[image: Distribution]

Comment: It reminded me of the Poisson distribution but as you are dealing with a continuous value I would recommend the gamma distribution (it is like the continuous counterpart of the discrete Poisson distribution)(https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution). The black one looks pretty much like the thing you need...

Comment: Finding the right class of densities is pretty much black art, magic, experience and googling :-D

Comment: The *right* way is to use your physical knowledge to suggest reasonable forms for the function.

Comment: @FabianWerner.  It appears that what is wanted is a regression that might happen to have a shape similar to that of a probability distribution.  That is a much different situation than having a random sample from the probability distribution.  (I say this because of the error bars in the above figure and that this seems to be a not uncommon confusion in some scientific fields.)

Comment: @JimB The errors come from the fact that this data is from MC but I actually just want a probability distribution that looks a bit like this so that I can use it to generate data points for a toy MC

Comment: @whuber It's the product of an exponential with some other complicated shape that comes from a multivariate output from a BDT with 30 or so parameters so generally hard to think about from a pure physics perspective

Comment: Sorry, I don't speak physics.  What's an "MC" ?  One of the issues you'll need to deal with for a regression is that the errors vary with B_TAU_ps and that B_TAU_ps is bounded by zero.  (That's on top of the selection of a curve form.)

Comment: Sorry, MC is Monte Carlo, so simulation

Comment: OK.  Thanks.  That term I do know.  I think if you described how you obtained the curve, you might bet more definitive answers.  (But, then again, it's still soon after the question was posted.)

Comment: I think I have a function now that works quite well, the Weibull distribution

Comment: What I was poorly trying to say is that the *shape* of the gamma distribution (with the right parameters) looks like the shape of the data curve above, i.e. take the function class $c*\gamma(\alpha,\beta)(\cdot)$ and fit it to the data using some optimizer...

Comment: @FabianWerner.  That makes perfect sense.  But what I see in some of these forums (particularly the *Mathematica* Stack Exchange) is that the use of $c$ or (adding a constant when the curve doesn't touch zero) and a standard optimizer doesn't recognize the non-constant variance and then the interpretation of the curve as if it were a probability distribution.